# mysqli_query with special characters

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

I'm using `mysqli_query()` with a dynamic variable `$categoryName`, where `$categoryName` will be dynamic where the category name will be fetch based on user submission from a form.

Within my category name submission form there are `Food, Vintage clothing, Leisure, Angel's` etc...

I'm still quite new to querying content from database, currently managed to come out with using `mysqli_query()` for querying from the database, like so:

```
$sqlCommand = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM products WHERE category='$categoryName'");
```

Everything works great and I managed to query the db with my existing category names, however there's only one which doesn't work is the `Angel's` category with `'` apostrophe symbol in it.

```
Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in.......
```

I suspect there is some sort of method like filter that need to be called before `mysqli_query()`?

Comment: Try using `$catName = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $categoryName);` then in the query use `$catName`

Comment: Use prepare and parameter binding. Otherwise you miss out the the advantages of `mysqli`.

Comment: @SamSwift웃 yes it works :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`mysqli_real_escape_string`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php)

```
$cat_name = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $categoryName);
$sqlCommand = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM products WHERE category='$cat_name'");
```

Answer (score 1):

This is called an **SQL-Injection**. In this case it's not wanted and occurs in normal business. You should read [an article](https://www.acunetix.com/websitesecurity/sql-injection/) about SQL-Injection and prevent it in future projects.

You can escape that string using

```
mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $categoryName);
```

Happy coding.

Comment: You need to add first parameter as connection string `mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $categoryName);`